# Set -dynlink in Bazel go rules

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules

When building a go binary using Bazel I'm trying to figure out how to set [`-dynlink` flag](https://golang.org/cmd/compile/)

I've checked most of the [available options](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/core.rst#go-binary) but unsure if it is possible.

It seems to be available [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/026db6df5ad760e9002f627bdb4f6b695c04d76a/go/tools/builders/stdlib.go#L35)

Comment: linkmode=plugin also seems to be the wrong approach

Comment: linkmode="pie" and gc_goopts=["-dynlink"] might of done the trick